# How to Follow the Path of a Super Ellipse with 2 Linked Axis

Tags: algorithm, linear-algebra, computational-geometry, graph-algorithm, trigonometry

I have two axis linked together ; Axis A, and Axis B. Axis B is attached to the end of Axis A and so its point of origin can vary with the angle of Axis A . Attached to Axis B is a Circle whose Diameter is 10 (and can become smaller). I need to move the edge point of the circle to intersect a Super-Ellipse at each of 38 Cartesian points x,y. So the end point of my axis B - center of the circle should follow the same basic path as the 38 points of the super ellipse - radius of circle. Once I have these points - I will need to determine the position of Axis A x_2,y_2 and angle (or more appropriately just the distance from 0 degree angle to reach the required angle to position x_2,y_2. I then need to position Axis B with relation to Axis A in order to have Axis B X_3,Y_3 match the following of the Super-Ellipse where the center of the circle is supposed to be.

I have a drawing attached and a plot in Excel where I am off as you can see the bow tie is not what I should have. I have also included the points to the super ellipse along with some quick points on the graph. I am not a math major - I am willing to learn if you post the name of an equation - so far I have learned about carnot, parametric equation for circles and formulas for parabolas - but I am still having trouble.

[image: Graphical Representation of the Problem]
[image: Excel Layout of plotting points - the inner path is not properly followed.]

```
Axis A Radius 13" image is 90 degree rotation
X_Sub1 , Y_Sub1 
-6.5   , 5

Axis B Radius 9" image is 180 degree rotation
X_Sub2 , Y_Sub2 
 6.5   , 5

Circle Diameter 10" 
Circle Radius 5" 

Super Ellipse 
@ 12"width
@ 8.75" Deep Vertex -8.75

Points Along the Super Ellipse.
0.0000,  0.0000
0.2188, -0.6250
0.2188, -1.2500
0.2433, -1.8750
0.3290, -2.5000
0.4753, -3.1073
0.6804, -3.7091
0.9424, -4.2990
1.2585, -4.8712
1.6255, -5.4197
2.0397, -5.9388
2.4967, -6.4233
2.9920, -6.8682
3.5203, -7.2889
4.0764, -7.7213
4.6544, -8.0500
5.2285, -8.3553
5.7525, -8.5000
6.2188, -8.5516
6.6851, -8.5000
7.1891, -8.3553
7.7832, -8.0500
8.3612, -7.7213
8.9173, -7.2889
9.4456, -6.8682
9.9409, -6.4233
10.3979,-5.9388
10.8121,-5.4197
11.1791,-4.8712
11.4952,-4.2990
11.7572,-3.7091
11.9623,-3.1073
12.1086,-2.5000
12.1943,-1.8750
12.2188,-1.2500
12.2188,-0.6250
12.4376, 0.0000
```

Answer (score 0):

First, suppose we have 3 points along the super-ellipse, `p0 = (2.4967, -6.4233)`, `p1 = (2.9920, -6.8682)`, and `p2 = (3.5203, -7.2889)`.  Let's figure out how to position it to touch the point `p1`.

First of all at the point `p1` the tangent line should be very close to parallel to the line from `p0` to `p2`.  So it should be parallel to `p2 - p0 = (3.5203, -7.2889) - (2.4967, -6.4233) = (1.0236, -0.8656)`.  But you want the disk to be perpendicular to this.  We can construct a perpendicular to the vector `(x, y)` by `(-y, x)`, which gives us `(0.8656, 1.0236)` as a direction.  (There are two perpendiculars, looking at the diagram this is obviously the correct one.)  This means that we want to put the end of axis B a distance of `5` in that direction.  Which means it needs to be a distance of `5` in the direction `(0.8656, 1.0236)` from `p1 = (2.9920, -6.8682)`.  So it should be at the position `(2.9920, -6.8682) + 5 * (0.8656, 1.0236) / sqrt(0.8656^2 + 1.0236^2) = (6.22057, -3.050307)`.

Now that we know where the end of axis B is, assuming we know where the start of axis A is (you didn't specify that), we can use the law of cosines (see http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LawofCosines.html) to figure out the cos of the angles that you want.  Now you can use the arccosine function to figure out the angles in question.

This procedure can be followed for every point.  Figure out what you think it should be tangent to, find the orthogonal, find where you want the end of B to be, then you have a triangle that you can use the cosine law on.